# Why am I getting "keyword can't be an expression"?

Tags: python

Ok, so I have this as an assignment (I'm in an intro course right now).

Write a function `make_x_table (r,c):` that creates a multiplication table of r rows and c cols where each entry = r*c and it returns it.

and I wrote this code for it:

```
def make_x_table (r,c):    
    for rownum in range(1, r+1):
        for colnum in range(1, c+1):
            v = colnum*rownum
            print(str(v) + ' ' + end='')
        print ()
```

Basically, this is an example of what I want:

```
make_x_table(3,4)
1 2 3 4
2 4 6 8
3 6 9 12
```

I keep getting an error saying "keyword can't be an expression" and it'll highlight the parentheses before `str(v)`. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Any help?

Comment: A guess: You are using python 2.x, but writing for python 3.x

Comment: Nope, I am using Python 3.3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

end is a **keyword argument** to the print function; Python's getting really confused that you're doing

```
print(str(v) + ' ' + end='')
#                  ^
```

in your print function.  You probably wanted to do

```
print(str(v) + ' ', end='')
#                 ^
```

Comment: Thnak you for that, I just got caught up with the + signs. Should've seen that myself!

Answer (score 2):

I suppose `print(str(v) + ' ' + end='')` should be `print(str(v) + ' ' + end + '')`

Comment: Nope, not working for me unfortunately. I'm using Python 3.3.4, if that helps

Comment: what is the type of `end` variable?

Comment: This is quite wrong. Read up on the print function in Python 3

Comment: Aaron, to be honest I don't see how this might we wrong if `end='text to output'` for example ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
print(str(v) + ' ' + end='')
```

Should probably be

```
print(str(v) + ' ', end='')
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
print(str(v) + ' ', end='')
```

You don't use the `+` operator to specify `end`, you put it as an argument so it's set off with a comma.

Comment: Wow, don't know how I didn't see that. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, here's a tip to help you debug these sorts of problems: start editing the line, chopping away one bit or another until the problem goes away.  I had to do that to figure this out; I got caught up in the `+` operators too! :-)